# discord.py save variable settings changes of server

Tags: python, heroku, discord, discord.py

how can I save `self.stn_hoist` value of each server when someone changes value to heroku postgres?

```
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def hoist(self, ctx, value):
    embed=discord.Embed(color=0x850000)
    embed.add_field(name="hoist", value=f'has been set to `{value}`.', inline=False)
      
    if value.lower() == 'yes':
        self.stn_hoist = True
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    elif value.lower() == 'no':
        self.stn_hoist = False
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(color=0x850000).add_field(name="hoist", value=f'can not be set to `{value}`'))
```

Comment: I added heroku postgres to heroku app and connected it to bot.py but I dont know how to create the database and save variable change

Comment: Do you want `stn_hoist` to be saved as a variable?

Comment: @Ceres I want to know how to save settings of each server like `stn_hoist` in a database and how to load `on_ready()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouln't recommend using a database for a single variable. You could go about using a json file for this, but heroku has an [ephemeral file system](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku), meaning that the json file is rewritten whenever your app restarts. You could use heroku's config variables to store this variable.

```py
import os
import requests
#getting the variable
hoist = os.environ['hoist']
# OR
request = requests.get('https://api.heroku.com/apps/YOUR-APP-NAME/config-vars', headers={'Accept': 'application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3', "Authorization": "Bearer YOUR-AUTH-TOKEN"})
if request.status_code == 200:
   hoist = request.json()['hoist']
else:
   print('something went wrong')

#updating the config variable

request = requests.patch('https://api.heroku.com/apps/YOUR-APP-NAME/config-vars', json.dumps({"hoist": "1"}), headers={"Content-Type": "application/json", 'Accept': 'application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3', "Authorization": "Bearer YOUR-AUTH-TOKEN"})
if request.status_code == 200:
   hoist = request.json()['hoist']
else:
   print('something went wrong')
```

You have to replace `YOUR-APP-NAME` with your apps name or id and `YOUR-AUTH-TOKEN` with your auth token.

You have to set the [config variable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) `hoist` in the heroku dashboard or CLI.

You can get the API token [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-quickstart#authentication)

### References:

- [API Docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#config-vars)
- [accessing config var](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#accessing-config-var-values-from-code)

### Further Reading:

- [Use heroku api wrapper](https://pypi.org/project/heroku3/)